# Neater Url Structure

Tags: php, apache

I am using PHP and Apache Server, and I would like to know how I could change my navigation structure from `www.website.com/?about` to `www.website.com/#about`?

Comment: Apache and PHP can't read the hash string, so you can't use them for rewrites etc.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to rewrite a query parameter name (about in this case) as an anchor name for page?

Comment: I would just like a neater way of making the URL it does not have to be the # symbol I would be happy if I could get it so that its www.example.com\about but I dont want to go making a folder for every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  `#` denotes the [*fragment identifier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), and it's resolved on the client-side (the browser simply scrolls to the anchor called `about`).  It's not sent to the server.

However, if you want to use e.g. `www.website.com/about`, then you can do that.  You need to use *mod_rewrite*, see the [Apache URL rewriting guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I saw it being done on another site. Do you know how I would make it so the URL would read, www.website.com/page/about/

Comment: Thanks Oli This appears to be what I was looking for. I found a more beginner friendly link over here. http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This website has some great examples.
http://www.bloghash.com/2006/12/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Exactly what I was looking for.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]